# Count the number of timestamp instances with an interval in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a text-file with the following timestamps:

0:01

0:02

0:02

0:02

0:03

...

2:05:52

2:05:52

2:05:52

2:05:53

2:05:53

2:05:53

2:05:53

2:05:54

2:05:54

2:05:54

2:05:54

Currently, I have a dictionary set up that counts each instance and counts them. The output [2:05:54, 4]. Which is great and all and ranks the most occurrence. However, a problem I noticed is if I don't group them in some kind of interval, a 30 sec segment will take up all the space. I can have in theory and currently, timestamps 1:00 - 1:30 taking up all the space. Which is why I want to group them in some kind of interval, hopefully with Pandas? What I see from Pandas is I need to have it in MM-DD-YYYY TIMESTAMP, which is something I can not do.

Comment: I do have some ideas, however it is currently 1:00 AM.

The idea I have is lets say I have 20 dictionaries total. The first 5 being
[0:00, 5]
[0:01, 1]
[0:02, 0]
[0:03, 2]
[0:04, 7]

It would group the first value[0:00 and 0:04] and just add them.

Another idea would to just generate all the values, have a dictionary of 0:00 to 9:99:99 and group them before I read the text file. Just some ideas I have and will look to implementing in the morning.

Comment: For anyone who is looking at this. Don't bother. The code doesn't work and the method below doesn't work for me. I'm keeping it up, since it may prove to be useful to someone else. I have some other method I'm working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to clean your data.  I don't know whether "0:01" means 1 second after midnight or one minute after, and neither does Pandas.  Write it as "0:00:01" or "0:01:00" as appropriate.  Then try this:

```
df = pd.read_table('mydata.txt', header=None)
df.index = pd.to_timedelta(df[0]) # convert from strings
df.resample('1 min').count()
```

The output is:

```
           0
0           
00:00:01   5
00:01:01   0
00:02:01   0
00:03:01   0
00:04:01   0
...       ..
02:01:01   0
02:02:01   0
02:03:01   0
02:04:01   0
02:05:01  11
```

Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll look into cleaning it with some ": [colon]" counters or something. These are actually timestamps of comments from a YouTube stream. 0:01 being a comment being typed one sec after the stream went live. I'll get to it in the morning!